# Crash Report for notifications Android

Tags: java, android, crash, broadcastreceiver, extras

guys. How are you all doing? Good I hope.

I have a question regarding crash reports from my app, more specifically when receiving a notification. As far as I was able to test the application, it had no issues with showing it's notifications, but in Google Play Console, I have multiple crash reports, telling me that there has been a `Null Pointer Exception`

This is my crash report right here:

> java.lang.RuntimeException:    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3098)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18 (ActivityThread.java)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1588) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6247)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (ZygoteInit.java:872)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>
> (ZygoteInit.java:762) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException:    at
>   com.tedosoft.carmaintenance.AlertReceiver.onReceive
>   (AlertReceiver.java:24)   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver
>   (ActivityThread.java:3091)

And this is the specific line `(AlertReceiver.java:24)` in my code:

```
if (intent.getStringExtra("id").equals("autoUpdate"))
```

And the full code to that line:

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null){
            if (intent.getStringExtra("id").equals("autoUpdate")) {
                doAutoUpdate(context, context.getString(R.string.notification_auto_add_title),
                        context.getString(R.string.notification_auto_add_text),
                        context.getString(R.string.notification_auto_add_title));
            }
```

The entire code for `onReceive`

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null){
        if (intent.getStringExtra("id").equals("autoUpdate")) {
            doAutoUpdate(context, context.getString(R.string.notification_auto_add_title),
                    context.getString(R.string.notification_auto_add_text),
                    context.getString(R.string.notification_auto_add_title));
        }
        if (intent.getStringExtra("id").equals("updateReminder")) {
            createNotification(context, context.getString(R.string.notification_title),
                    context.getString(R.string.notification_text),
                    context.getString(R.string.notification_title));
        }
        if (intent.getStringExtra("id").equals("reminder")) {
            List<Integer> activeRemindersRowIds = getActiveRemindersCarRowIds(context);
            for (int j = 0; j < activeRemindersRowIds.size(); j++) {
                createNotificationReminder(context, activeRemindersRowIds.get(j),
                        context.getString(R.string.notification_reminder_text),
                        context.getString(R.string.notification_reminder_ticker));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I suspect I am doing wrong here, is that most probably I should be typing in `if(extras.getString("id).equals("autoUpdate"))` instead of what it is at the moment, but I would like you to confirm that for me, before jumping to any conclusions.

So what I am asking here is - Why is my application crashing on that line of code and how can I fix this?

The crash report is only for that line and the other `if statements` do not cause crashes.

Comment: Thank you, Marcin, for your quick feedback. I am aware of what a null pointer exception is and what could cause it, but I am actually having trouble identifiying exactly from where this null value is coming from. That is why I am asking for help from you guys.

Comment: String idReceived = intent.getStringExtra("id");

idReceived could be null. You can check for it. And to avoid NPE better way of comparison will be as 

 if ( "autoUpdate".equals(intent.getStringExtra("id"))) { 
..............
}

Comment: You have a good point there. Thank you for your comment. I will do a correction to my code and monitor if crash reports will stop.

If anyone has another idea, feel free to give it here. Thanks!